# Firefox distorts background-image when scrolling

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

I'm working on a calendar feature for a webapp and am running into trouble with firefox.

I am using a background image (dimensions: 2x42) and `background-repeat: repeat` so the image takes up the entire space.

In Chrome it looks fine, like this: [image: All horizontal lines are clean.]

But Firefox distorts the image like this: [image: Some horizontal lines have wider sections producing strange notches.]

I'm thinking that this is some Firefox rendering bug, because when I scroll, the image sometimes looks fine.

I managed to replicate the issue here
https://jsfiddle.net/12jnh5p8/

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/FPC8ydW.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Edit: I found out this happens when you use Windows' scaling option. I am using a 2560 x 1440 monitor with 125% scaling. When I change scaling to 100%, the problem disappears

Comment: I also have the same issue in Chrome with zooming on my monitor... But I would say: You don't need any image for this background anyhow, you can do this with normal CSS linear-gradient and hard stops.

Comment: Maybe relevant: I've seen similar glitches in (straight) linear gradients in https://twitter.com/myfonj/status/1487959043276685317 and possibly related in diagonal. Reported the latter as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1763221 . Both are using `linear-gradient()`, not `url()`, though.